Do quarks in QCD belong to $\mathbb{C}^3$ or $\mathbb{C}^4$?
Quarks are known to have spin 1/2 which means they belong to $\mathbb{C}^4$. At the same time in QCD the gauge group is $SU(3)$ which has a natural representation over $\mathbb{C}^3$, and in fact I have read that quarks in this theory have three components. Does this mean that these quarks belong to $\mathbb{C}^3$? This would explain why quarks have three colors since there is one for every component. But doesn't this contract them being spin 1/2 particles which usually belong to $\mathbb{C}^4$?

Whenever you have something that transforms in one way under a group $A$ in a representation $V_A$ of $A$ and independently under a group $B$ in a representation $V_B$ of $B$, this is equivalent to saying it transforms in the tensor product $V_A\otimes V_B$, which is naturally a representation of $A\times B$.
For quarks, this just looks like this: The quark fields $\psi^{\mu a}$ have two indices, the spinor index $\mu$ running from 0 to 3 and the color index $a$ running from 1 to 3, making altogether 12 components - $\mathbb{C}^4\otimes\mathbb{C}^3 \cong \mathbb{C}^{12}$ - of a quark field.

Thank you. The math is now clear but I'm still trying to wrap my head around some of the physics. If a quark belong to $\mathbb{C}^4 \otimes \mathbb{C}^3$ then each of the four degrees of freedom given by the spinor has its own 3 degrees of freedom. Does this mean the gauge group acts on each component of the spinor separately? Is there any physical reason behind that?

@CBBAM That gauge groups can only combine with the spacetime symmetry group in this "trivial" way, i.e. acting on each of the components separately, is the content of the Coleman-Mandula theorem.
